# Connecting to SQL Server on Parallels Desktop with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, macos, virtualization

well I recently bought a Mac and am using it as my primary computer.

Because I am required to work with MSSQL via PHP, I have installed Parallels Desktop and run Server 2008 R2 on it. I am using the same mixed mode authentication which I previously had on windows.

When I attempt to connect to the server with PHP using either a new test file or my old code, it just doesn't find the server.

I have tried running PHP on the XP install with parallels, and using the hostname as `COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS`, `LOCALIP\SQLEXPRESS` `localhost` `localip` etc, PHP never finds the server.

Please note that both PHP and MSSQL are running within the virtualised environment.

Also note that I can connect to the database server using Management Studio without problems, so SQL Server is running.

Any contribution is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how your host OS communicates with the virtual Parallels environment, but by default the network protocols for remote access to SQL Express are disabled:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165677.aspx

So if your PHP application is trying to use TCP/IP to connect to SQL Express, then you need to enable the protocol first.

If this doesn't help, you might get a better answer on serverfault.com, because your issue has more to do with system configuration than with development.